# Python: FuncAnimation doesn't work in "while True" loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, graph, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi connected with an accelerometer. In Python, I'm want to draw a animated graph of X-axis value. It's a realtime graph that shows the change of X-axis value as I move the Pi in my hand. However the graph shows only the initial value.

```
from mpu6050 import mpu6050
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use("fivethirtyeight")

sensor = mpu6050(0x68)
print " waiting for the sensor to callibrate..."

sleep(2)

acc = np.empty((0,3), float) # storage for x, y, z axes values of the accelerometer
t = 0
time = np.empty((0,1), int) # time counter(this becomes the x axis of the graph)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

axis = 0 # accelerometer x axis. y axis = 1, z axis = 2

def animate(i):
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(time, acc[:,axis])

while True:
    accel_data = sensor.get_accel_data()
    print("Accelerometer data")
    print("x: " + str(accel_data['x']))
    print("y: " + str(accel_data['y']))
    print("z: " + str(accel_data['z']))
    acc = np.append(acc, np.array([[accel_data['x'], accel_data['y'], accel_data['z']]]), axis=0)

    # increment time array
    time = np.append(time, t)
    t = t + 1

    print("acc[:,0]:" + str(acc[:,0]))
    print("time:" + str(time))
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 1000)
    plt.show()
    sleep(2)
```

However, when I run the script, it only prints the value in the first loop like below. It also shows the graph but it's an empty graph because in the first loop there is only one data point.

```
waiting for the sensor to callibrate...
Accelerometer data
x: 6.2009822998
y: 3.36864173584
z: 9.27513723145
acc[:,0]: [ 6.2009823]
time: [0]
```

[image]

When I close the graph window, the loop resumes from the second loop and prints the values onwards, but the graph is never shown again.

Although it does not give any Error message, I assume something is wrong with `animation.FuncAnimation` or the place I should put `plt.show()` in the `while` loop.

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3b + with Python 2.7.13. Accelerometer is MPU6050.

It would be great if anybody could tell me how to fix this problem. Thank you!

Comment: No, you should not use a while loop at all. The `FuncAnimation` itself can be seen as the loop that you want to use to change your plot.

Comment: Thank you! But in order to continuously read and print the value from the accelerometer, I used while loop. Could you elaborate a bit more on how to use `FuncAnination` without while loop, and at the same time constantly read the value from the accelerometer?

Comment: `FuncAnimation` repeatedly calls a function (in your case `animate`). Inside this function you do whatever you need to in order to continuously read and print the value from the accelerometer.

Comment: Okay, so you mean I should read the accelerometer values inside the `animate` function only once, then `FuncAnimation` will call `animate` repeatedly, with updated accelerometer values? Hope I understood you correctly.